# How to quickly reformat a partition to effectively empty the disk?

Tags: centos, partition

My drive is 18TB and it is filled to the brim with junk I don't want, and there are so many millions of files that it would take days or weeks to delete it all using `rm -rf`.

I want to do the equivalent of a quick format in Windows.
[image]

I do not want to overwrite the whole drive with zeros or random data, as this would shorten the lifespan of the drive, take forever, and is unnecessary.

So I'm trying to reformat, but no luck with just running this command:

```
root: ~ # sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdd1

mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sdd1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

the drive is not mounted:

```
root:~ # umount /dev/sdd1
umount: /dev/sdd1: not mounted
```

some output

```
root:~ # lsblk
sdd
└─sdd1          ext4              [UUID REMOVED FOR THIS POST]
```

here's the fdisk output for this drive:

```
root:~ # fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdd: 18000.2 GB, 18000207937536 bytes, 35156656128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: [UUID here]
```

`df -h` doesn't show it in the list, because it's unmounted now as I wanted.

`fuser -vm /dev/sdd` and `fuser -vm /dev/sdd1` comes up blank, no output.

`lsof | grep /dev/sdd1` comes up blank, no output.

Let me know what other output you may need to help.

How can I destroy all data by reformatting the partition without overwriting the whole drive? I basically want to do a quick format, or just delete and re-add the partition, whichever is best.

Comment: All data was successfully destroyed instantly using my method of deleting the partition. I then reinitilized the disk. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can erase the superblock of the partition very easily to fool `mkfs` into thinking there is no filesystem:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd1 bs=1k count=2
```

If you then re-run your `sudo mkfs` command, it should happily format your partition giving you a brand new empty filesystem.

You can also use `-F -F` without erasing the superblock to "... force [mkfs] to create a filesystem even if the filesystem appears to be in use or is mounted (a truly dangerous thing to do)..." (taken from `man mkfs.ext4`).

Like this:

```
mkfs.ext4 -F -F /dev/sdd1
```

Comment: The `dd` command will take fractions of a second - effectively instant. The `mkfs` command will take longer - the bigger your partition, the longer it takes.

Comment: Neither of these truly overwrites the filesystem. The `mkfs` command will write a small amount of data to the superblock and to copies of the superblock throughout the filesystem. The `dd` command will write a total of 2048 bytes to the beginning on the partition.

Comment: The `dd` command takes input from it `if` device - `/dev/null` - and writes to the `of` device - `/dev/sdd1` (the disk partition you want to clean up). It specifies a block size of 1k (1024 bytes) and a count of 2 (2 blocks). See `man dd`.

Comment: It's the null device. It's a part of UNIX / Linux. It's a source of zeros.

Comment: `man dd` and `man mkfs.ext4` are your friends.

Comment: `bs=` and `count=` have nothing to do with `fdisk`. They are parameters to the `dd` command. `bs` is measures in bytes. `count` is a non-negative integer number of blocks.

Comment: There is no "same as current". Running `mkfs.ext4 -F -F /dev/sdd1` will force a reformat of the partition in question.

Comment: I never said anything about recommended. I said it is a dangerous thing to do. Which it is. But you WANT to do a dangerous thing. You want to delete your data. Deleting data is ALWAYS dangerous.

Comment: The `dd` command by itself will NOT result in a usable filesystem. The `mkfs.ext4 -F -F` by itself WILL result in a usable filesystem. Please go read (and re-read until you understand) the manual pages.

Comment: @unixaddict What does 'didn't work' mean? Helping out when we don't know what the problem is can be difficult.

Comment: @unixaddict please abide by the Code of Conduct; I've deleted a rude comment from you. Such language will not be tolerated here on SE.

Answer (score 1):

1. HDDs are generally not (as) affected (as SSDs) by the amount of data you're writing.
2. It's considered a good practice to write zeros to your *entire* partition when creating a new one. Why? It will prevent you from discovering old files. It will help you recover new deleted files as your partition won't have old junk.
3. > /dev/sdd1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!

Is a correct error in order to prevent you from destroying your data. If you read `man mke2fs` (the same utility creates ext2/3/4 partitions) you'd discover:

*-F     Force  mke2fs to create a file system, even if the specified device is not a partition on a block special device, or if other parameters do not make sense.  In order to force mke2fs to create a file system even if the file system appears to be in use or is mounted (a truly dangerous thing to do), this option must be specified twice.*

`ext4` might not be a good fit for such a huge partition. I'd recommend using XFS instead but it's my personal preference, so you can dismiss it with prejudice.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get you.

Comment: But I don't see any full commands so I don't see what to do from your answer.

Comment: `sudo mkfs -t ext4 -F /dev/sdd1` should work.

Comment: @unixaddict Because the fs was `ext4` in the past doesn't mean that it is the best choice for your disk and/or use case. There are very valid reasons to move to `xfs` or `zfs`.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Type  `-F` twice: `sudo mkfs -t ext4 -F -F /dev/sdd1` . Make sure it's **not** mounted, e.g. `mount | grep sdd` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It's less common on Hard Disks than SSDs, but if you have a self-encrypting disk you can cryptographically erase it by causing it to forget the internal encryption key and generate a new one.  Even if you don't use the feature most disks which have it encrypt transparently by default so it can be secured later with no conversion process.

```
hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --sanitize-crypto-scramble /dev/sdd
```

Would work in that case and be the most optimal combination of fast and effective.

It won't work on only one partition though so you'd have to repartition.

To discover if your disk supports any sanitize features you can query the command set with hdparm:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sdd
```

Comment: Good answer, for some use cases. My disk is not encrypted though. But good for others

Comment: Also I meant crypto-scramble.  Block erase is the erase-the-flash-as-fast-as-physically-possible option.  fixed